# Как убрать в ListView

Tags: c#, uwp

Ребят помогите пожалуйста. Как отключить анимацию кликанья элементов в ListView? 
Никак не могу информацию в гугле найти. P.S. Элементы создаются по шаблону.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD 
Код разметки:

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="ImageList"  Margin="0,10,0,0" Loaded="Main_lst_Loaded" >
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5,0,9" CornerRadius="5">                                                                              
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>   
</ListView>
```

Comment: О чем речь? можете подробнее описать?

Comment: @Андрей в ListView создаются элементы и каждый элемент по анимации схож с кнопкой(прожимается при нажатии выделяется нажатый элемент). А мне нужно чтобы это были просто кирпичи без какой либо реакции на нажатия(но событие ItemClick все равно должно обрабатываться)

Comment: Ну так код разметки приведите

Comment: @Андрей  Добавил разметку

Comment: Это всё что ли?

Comment: @Андрей это разметка моего ListView) И мне просто нужно убрать кликанье по элементам

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы элементы нельзя было выделять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если надо чтобы получился просто список без анимации нажатия, то:

```
<ListView
        SelectionMode="None" />
```

Comment: Это практически то, что нужно. Только еще вопрос, как сделать чтобы при наведении мышкой на элемент у него не затемнялся фон?

Comment: Либо выпиливать лишнее из стиля `ListView`, либо использовать  `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Можно немного по-подробнее про второе

Comment: Вместо `ListView` использовать `ItemsControl`. Это стандартный списочный контрол, есть из коробки. Используется практически так же.